# Differential CVD waveform in PIC18F45K50

Tags: pic, c, microchip, capacitive

I am using [PIC18f45K50](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC18F2X_45K50-30000684B.pdf) for capacitive touch button using a differential CVD ([Capacitive Voltage Divider](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/TB3198_CVD_90003198A.pdf)).
My capacitive button works. However I am not able to get the standard differential CVD waveform suggested by Microchip.

Has someone worked on differential CVD and could guide me or point me in the correct direction?

Currently this is how my waveform looks in a scope which is way different then the standard waveform suggested by Microchip:

Standard waveform
[image]

Edit2: New waveform and the code for ADC channel
[image]

And here is the code

```
unsigned long int result;
ADCON0bits.CHS = 14;// Set channel to the previous sensor
CVD_CHARGE_TRIS=0; Nop();CVD_CHARGE_LAT=1;
channel1=0;trischannel1=0;
// Start Pre-charge
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
trischannel1=1;//Disconnect current sensor from GND (HI-Z)
GUARD_LAT=1;
//Acquisition 
ADCON0bits.CHS=adcchanselect[0];
Nop();Nop();
ADCON0bits.GO_NOT_DONE = 1; // Start conversion
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
while (ADCON0bits.GO_NOT_DONE){}
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
//trischannel1=0;//Ground sensors
//CVD_CHARGE_LAT=0;
result=ADC_GetConversionResult();
//Scan B
ADCON0bits.CHS = 14;// Set channel to the previous sensor
CVD_CHARGE_TRIS = 0;Nop();CVD_CHARGE_LAT = 0;//Set previous sensor to Gnd (discharge internal)
channel1=1;trischannel1=0;//Set current sensor to GND (charge external)
// Start Pre-charge
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
trischannel1=1;//Disconnect current sensor from GND (HI-Z)
GUARD_LAT=0;
//Acquisition
ADCON0bits.CHS=adcchanselect[0];
Nop();Nop();
ADCON0bits.GO_NOT_DONE = 1; // Start conversion 
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();Nop();
while (ADCON0bits.GO_NOT_DONE){}
channel1=0;    // Ground sensors
trischannel1=0;
result+=(1024-ADC_GetConversionResult());
return result;
```

Comment: What does the standard waveform look like?

Comment: Edited the original question to add standard cvd waveform

Answer (score 1):

First off, I assume;

- You are referring to using the inbuilt ADC without any external hardware as per Microchip's application note AN1478 (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01478A.pdf)
- Your scope is set to AC coupling (otherwise that -1.5V peak would have fried your PIC)

Just setting your oscilloscope to DC coupling will most likely get you a waveform that will resemble much more the image which you supplied (also in the application note I linked). I would also recommend increasing your time spent in the pre-charge phase. It is difficult to be sure in AC coupling but it looks to me like it does not have time to reach the full scale voltage before you transition to the acquisition phase.

Comment: No I have DC coupling set on my oscilloscope

Comment: In that case I assume that you have not connected your probe's ground to your test circuit's ground. If your sensor was connected directly to your PIC, a -1.5V peak would fry your pin. I can only assume that either the information you have provided is incomplete or that there is a measurement error.

Comment: I did not test the circuit's ground I just assumed that the ground would be same. I will add my code and new waveform that I received

Comment: Im sorry but the code you posted is dense and hard to read. In general, doing less things in more lines is easier to read than dense multiple statements per line code. There are also many macros(I assume) that are defined elsewere in the code. As far as your new waveform goes, it never reaches VDD therefore it seems you are not precharging the sensore to VDD (one of the two cycles described in the application note).